# Slow join behaviour with 'or' in predicate

Tags: oracle, join, oracle-10g, plsql

I'm faced with a situation which I can't understand and overcome.

In short we have left-join query like:

```
select from a 
left join b on a.key1=b.key1 or a.key1=b.key2
```

This works VERY slowly, while at the same time both separately:

```
select from a 
left join b on a.key1=b.key1

select from a 
left join b on a.key1=b.key2
```

work very fast.

b.key1 has normal index

b.key2 has normal index

I can't understand the reason for such behavior? Am I missing something very basic in my join strategy or index usage?

Here we go with detailed plans:

WITHOUT OR(TOP_USTR_ADMIN_IP - index name for ustrip column):

```
SQL> explain plan for
SELECT * FROM top.macs_constraint mc 
LEFT JOIN top.top_ustr tu ON  tu.ustrip = mc.IP;

Explained.

SQL> SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY());

   Plan hash value: 349751289

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name              | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |                   |     1 |    22 |  1296   (1)| 00:00:16 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE        |                   |     1 |    22 |            |              |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER|                   |   981K|    20M|  1296   (1)| 00:00:16 |
|*  3 |    INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| TOP_USTR_ADMIN_IP | 23187 |   181K|    62   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL   | MACS_CONSTRAINT   |   629K|  8601K|  1231   (1)| 00:00:15 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("TU"."USTRIP"(+)="MC"."IP")
   3 - filter("TU"."USTRIP"(+) IS NOT NULL)
```

WITH OR:

```
explain plan for
SELECT count(*) FROM top.macs_constraint mc 
LEFT JOIN top.top_ustr tu ON (tu.ustrip = mc.IP or tu.skladIP = mc.IP);  

Explained.

SQL> SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY());

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2704565128

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |                 |     1 |    14 |   322M  (1)|999:59:59 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE      |                 |     1 |    14 |            |            |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS OUTER |                 |  1887K|    25M|   322M  (1)|999:59:59 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL | MACS_CONSTRAINT |   629K|  8601K|  1231   (1)| 00:00:15 |
|   4 |    VIEW              |                 |     3 |       |   513   (1)| 00:00:07 |
|*  5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| TOP_USTR        |     3 |    72 |   513   (1)| 00:00:07 |

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   5 - filter("TU"."SKLADIP" IS NOT NULL AND "TU"."SKLADIP"="MC"."IP" OR  
              "TU"."USTRIP" IS NOT NULL AND "TU"."USTRIP"="MC"."IP")
```

Why does using `or` in the predicate give nested loops and no index usage? Is it possible to force index usage?

**UPDATED:**
missattached wrong plan for "without or".fixed

Comment: If you rewrite with 2 subqueries and `UNION ALL` you get duplicates or not?

Comment: Yes, union all on two queries produces result with dups if I got your question

Comment: So if you use `UNION` (without `ALL`) is it faster or slower? Different plan?

Comment: How many rows are really in `TOP_USTR`?

Comment: 1 yes, using union is faster, because each separate join uses indexes. Question was why 'or'-predicate does not =) Hansen answer below states that it seems to be well known, but I'v never met such info.Well I am no way a DB guru...

2 top_ustr has about 130k mc has about 660k

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OR is slower because you no longer can perform an index seek, but effectively forces the database engine to look through each leaf node in your index tree. 
With a single parameter (no OR), the engine can seek down through the index to the relevant leaf nodes, but when you ask it an OR, it scans the entire range of leaf nodes.

If the performance is too slow to tolerate, do as the comments suggest and try a UNION (no duplicate values) or a UNION ALL (allow duplicate values), or even two separate queries on their own and then join the results together in the code layer receiving the results.

Comment: Is it whell known that using 'or' in join predecate leades to " look through each leaf node in your index tree"? Can I read in some specs ?

Comment: I'd say it's "well known" index behavior (anything is well known, if you know if of course :))

However - you could look at for example: https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/or_expansion_transformation where they explain changing ORs into UNIONS for the same reasons and where they also mention to avoid table scans.

Comment: Wow, impressive link!